# Mythical caucasian in future Africa captured and sealed in tomb kills his woman eats her liver and goes into suspended animation

Tags: story-identification

The story involves a black African (despotic?) civilisation postdating the demise of the west becoming aware of a semi-mythical caucasian  who as a remnant of the extinguished western civilization must be eliminated as he is perceived to be a threat to African society.  I recall the end vividly - he is captured with his paramour, he is about to be sealed into a glass lidded tomb-like coffin structure and he kills his woman and then rips out "gobbets" of her liver, kidney and heart and them down sickening his captors.  His intention is to go into suspended animation with the high protein organs sustaining him until he can be rescued by his army of western remmants and lead them to victory over the Africans.

Comment: When would that have been published, roughly? And is that a book, a short story...?

Comment: Also, I hope he ate the liver with some fava beans and a nice Chianti?

Comment: Short story from late 20th C by a well known contemporaneous SF author who I cannot recall.  The story concerned a black African civilization postdating demise of western civilization - the mythical white man intends to destroy the African civilization. On his capture he kills his woman (snaps her neck) and tears her liver, heart and kidneys out of her body and eats them, pending arrival of his caucasian army.  He will enter a state of suspended animation until their arrival - the organs are high calorie and nutrition and will sustain him until that time.  No fava beans...

Comment: Alright; please [edit] that into the question so that all the info is gathered in one place, rather than scattered in the comments :)

Comment: Done.  Political correctness be damned.

Comment: Sounds a bit remnant of Phillip Jose Farmer.

Comment: No, this story was more hard science than PKF's style.  Also, I ran through his short story and novella biblio and there's nothing there in the time frame (1980's ->) which fits. It was something which you might encounter in Analog back in Campbell's day - I don't think Campbell would have countenanced PKF.

Comment: @thang what sort of medium was it? A novel? A short story?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your response.  It was a short story or at most a novella.  It may have been in a hard scifi mag such as Analog.  It was extremely well written and was probably authored by a well known SF master such as Silverberg for example.